# tensorflow: deal with variable length tensors

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

I'm into a situation that I need to transform things like

```
[[1,2,3,-1]
 [1,2,-1,-1]
 [1,-1,-1,-1]]
into 
[[1,2,3]
 [1,2]
 [1]]
```

for which -1 are paddings that I need to remove, I have tried map_fn, but it needs each unpacked tensor to have same shape after the process, I tried while loop in TF, but also the loop vars need to be tensors, and a list with variable length tensors can not be passed in, how can achieve this simple function?

Comment: Show your code?

Comment: @coldspeed thank you, the idea is simple, but it is not allowed in TF, how would you implement this function?

Comment: I made a mistake, TF while loop is the way to go

Comment: Yes, a while loop should work, although you may also consider whether you can solve your problem using vectorized operations (e.g. using a mask), since it would most likely be much faster (but may not be possible depending on the use case).

Comment: @jdehesa I see, thank you